# Avoid ssh session time out

Tags: session, ssh, exit

I am remotely working on a server that automatically logs me out after 5 minutes of inactivity.  Here's the message that it usually provides when it does so:

```
Read from remote host XXXXXXX: Operation timed out
```

I typically have several sessions open, which I use at roughly 30-minute intervals, so I wonder what I could do to avoid getting disconnected.  I've already tried:

- [a] hiring a monkey to hit some keys before the session logs me out
- [b] running the `top` command
- [c] threatening the server administrator :)

Any other suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: If you really have talked to the sysadmins and they say no, then anything you could do would probably violate IT policy and then you'd get spanked. Yes, you may disagree with the policy, but it is their policy.

Comment: What are you using for your client? Many have a "keep alive" feature built in...

Comment: I am using just Mac OS X Lion, I will like for that feature

Comment: http://www.quora.com/How-can-I-configure-my-terminal-on-Mac-OS-X-to-keep-SSH-connections-alive-even-when-they-are-idle

Comment: Taking into account Andrew's suggestion I found this: http://www.quora.com/How-can-I-configure-my-terminal-on-Mac-OS-X-to-keep-SSH-connections-alive-even-when-they-are-idle (NB. This link requires a Quora account or Facebook login to view the answer)

Answer (score 4):

This has been answered on StackOverFlow - I add the link here for people that don't want to go to a third party forum when they search for this answer (as I did):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390710/mac-terminals-how-to-keep-alive

Add to ~/.ssh/config

```
ServerAliveInterval 30
```

or start your ssh session using:

```
ssh -o ServerAliveInterval 30 username@hostname
```

And BTW: the answer is not specific to Mac.

Answer (score -5):

You might consider using `vi` or `more` to edit a file.

Comment: How will that help?  After 5 minutes of inactivity, it will stil time out?!

Comment: This answer is not relevant. Consider removing.