# Avoiding auto time out while doing ssh on remote servers

Tags: macos, ssh, timeout

I am working on a remote server which logs me out after 900 secs as the TMOUT variable is set to 900. I want my ssh client to send a noop packet to this server after say every 60 secs so that I would not be timed out of the remote server.

For this I have already tried added the following configs :

a) Putting Just the ServerAliveInterval in ~/.ssh/config :

```
ServerAliveInterval 60
```

b) Putting the host specific ServerAliveInterval in ~/.ssh/config :

```
Host *
 SendEnv LANG LC_*
 ServerAliveInterval 60
```

c) Using the "ServerAliveInterval" in the command line :

```
ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=60 username@hostname
```

I can see that in all the three cases, a packet is being sent after every 60 secs to these servers (Used the activity monitor app in Mac OS X to figure it out). Still the remote server is kicking me out after every 900 secs.

Can anybody solve this ? 
Below is some extra information below which I consider useless in the context of this problem but might help.

1. Using the Terminal app in Mac OS X 10.9
2. After doing ssh on the server, I su to some other user.

PS : This question has already been asked on StackExchange and has been answered with the solutions I tried.([Avoid ssh session time out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373594/avoid-ssh-session-time-out)) Could not comment on the above mentioned link as I did not have 50 reputation points.

Comment: The other question is working around a different timeout. TMOUT controls how long the shell will wait at the command-line prompt without reading a line. SSH keepalive packets won't reset the timer in the shell.

Comment: Hi Kenster, 
Do we have any solution to reset the shell timer ?